# Can I put a I fox 40 on 2018 Commencal Supreme SX?

Tags: frames, compatibility, suspension, downhill, fox

I recently bought a Commencal supreme SX, which came with a double crown fork. The bike was a really good deal and I had never had a dh bike. This was one of my only selections, so let me know if I should change it to the original fork or if you think it will be a tank on the trails. My local bike park is Snowshoe in West Virginia, USA.

Comment: If you're saying it has a different fork now and you're looking for an evaluation of the pros and cons of going back to a 40 or another double crown DH fork, then we need to know what it has now.

Comment: The 2018 Supreme SX originally came with a Rockshox Lyrik, which is a single crown fork. The Fox 40 is a dual crown fork. What kind of fork do you have now?

Comment: It has a fox 40

Answer (score 5):

From reading frame has a straight 1.5" head tube, which means you can put pretty much any fork on it you like, using the right headset.

How it will change the bikes performance depends entirely depends on what you are changing from and what you are changing to. While the bike is marketed as an Enduro, its really more like a bike designed for shuttle or lift parks for the downhill fun, probably why this one has a triple crown.

If the current fork is significantly the same price and style as a proposed replacement, you are unlikely to get a significant advantage, maybe save a few hundred grams on something that is never going to be a light weight racer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input everyone